# Xaml convert to Xap file

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have windows phone application and I want to deploy it in windows phone store my concern is that I don't know how to convert the xaml file into xap file..

Comment: If you have anymore easy question like this find me on Twitter @Anth0nyRussell Do you need a device to test on?

Answer (score 2):

The XAP file is created when you build your application.
For more info regarding the topic, refer to the official MSDN document:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff928362(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can find the .xap file for your application in Project Path/Bin/Release/.Xap file.